# perimeter vs sum of chord lengths in polygon

Tags: geometry

Is there a relationship between the perimeter and (a bound on) the sum of all chords in a (convex) polygon?

UPDATE:

Given two polygons $A$ and $B$ with perimeters $P_A$ and $P_B$ is there a bound on the difference between the sum of the chord lengths in $A$ and the sum of the chord lengths in $B$.

Comment: A single chord has an upper bound on its length of half the perimeter. A convex polygon has $\dbinom{n}{2}-\dbinom{n}{1} = \dfrac{n^2-3n}{2}$ chords (where $n$ is the number of sides of the polygon). So, an upper bound (definitely not a least upper bound) would be $\dfrac{P}{2}\cdot \dfrac{n^2-3n}{2}$. Is that what you are looking for? I'm sure there are stricter bounds than that. But, your question is not very clear as to what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I am looking for a leas upper bound.
What I want to figure out eventually is: if I have polygon $A$ with perimeter $P_A$ and polygon $B$ with perimeter $P_B$, what can I say about how far the sum of chord lengths in $A$ can be from the sum of chord lengths in $B$

Comment: If you would, please update your question with specifics of what you are looking for. Most likely, a least upper bound will be fairly elusive in a problem like this. You may be able to get an asymptotic bound, or possibly a stricter bound than the one I just gave you, but it is unlikely that there will be an easily described least upper bound. What, specifically, would you consider a "decent" answer?

Comment: A lower bound would likely be $\dfrac{P}{2}$ since if a single chord has length approaching $\dfrac{P}{2}$, then the entire polygon is basically a line segment, so all other chords would have a length very close to zero. This is just intuition, and definitely not a formal lower bound by any means, but it is likely close. So, currently, an upper bound on the difference between the sums of the lengths of the chords is the maximum of $\dfrac{P_1(n_1^2-3n_1)}{4}-\dfrac{P_2}{2}$ and $\dfrac{P_2(n_2^2-3n_2)}{4}-\dfrac{P_1}{2}$.